# Calculate time difference for a given dataset

Tags: bash, datetime, awk, sed

I have a list of down/up times and need to calculate the total down time, per day

Here is a snippet of the original dataset:

```
Jan  1 00:09:56 changed state to down
Jan  1 00:10:02 changed state to up
Jan  1 00:10:45 changed state to down
Jan  1 00:10:52 changed state to up
Jan  1 00:11:45 changed state to down
Jan  1 00:11:52 changed state to up
Jan  2 00:14:55 changed state to down
Jan  2 00:15:05 changed state to up
Jan  2 00:15:35 changed state to down
Jan  2 00:16:41 changed state to up
Jan  3 00:05:22 changed state to down
Jan  3 00:05:28 changed state to up
Jan  3 23:59:58 changed state to down
Jan  4 00:00:19 changed state to up
Jan  4 00:49:28 changed state to down
Jan  4 00:49:34 changed state to up
```

What I'm asking for is an output like this:

```
Jan 1: 20 seconds
Jan 2: 76 seconds
Jan 3: 27 seconds
Jan 4: 6 seconds
```

---

I've written this script to get the timestamps into epoch time:

```
while read i; do
  datetime=$(echo $i | awk '{print $1" "$2" "$3}')
  epochtime=$(date -d "$datetime" +\%s)
  echo $epochtime
done < ./file
```

which will give me the data like this:

```
1640995796
1640995802
1640995845
1640995852
...
```

I can't seem to find a way to combine them to a single line so I can use this code (or similar):

```
for i in $epochtime; do
  starttime=$(awk '{print $2}')
  endtime=$(awk '{print $1}')
  delta=$(( endtime - starttime ))
  echo $delta
done
```

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the exact expected output given your posted sample input. Also - do you have or can you install GNU awk (which has builtin time functions that'd make it orders of magnitude faster than calling `echo` plus `awk` plus `date` from a shell loop)? Show in your question the output of `awk --version`.

Comment: I apologize, in one of my previous drafts I included that information but yes I have GNU Awk 4.0.2.  Also, I've edited the question to include the desired output.

Comment: You said `I need to calculate the time difference between...` so don't you want the difference output instead of or in addition to the timestamps? Your gawk version is pretty old btw, we're now on 5.1.1 - you're missing a lot of new functionality and bug fixes so you should upgrade that.

Comment: Yes, the difference between the two timestamps is what I'm after.  I need to sum all the differences for each day after that. Having the original timestamps on the same line as the difference is not required.

Comment: OK, so - please [edit] your question to show  the expected output. Regarding `I need to sum all the differences for each day after that.` - at this point that should be a separate question once you accept the answer you want for the question you asked.

Comment: I've revised the question. Thank you for your help so far, I appreciate it!

Comment: Please fix your question to show the **exact** output you want from the sample input you provide. No "x seconds" and no dates in the output that don't exist in the input - just the actual dates+numbers you want output from your posted input. And get rid of the `...` lines as we can't copy/paste and test with input containing placeholders. Make sure to include at least 1 case where the date calculation crosses a date threshold.

Comment: @EdMorton I've added those edits. Thank you for helping me clarify my question.

Comment: @SteveFrost: do you have python/perl/ruby installed? what versions?

Comment: @Fravadona: Python 2.7.5,  Perl 5.16.3,  No ruby

Comment: There are some problems with your output; for example, the downtime of Jan 3 should be 8 seconds

Comment: Nervermind my last comment. @EdMorton got you the desired output so if you need something different then you should create a new question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    prevSecs = currSecs
    prevDate = currDate
    currDate = $1 " " $2
    $1 = (index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",$1) + 2) / 3
    currSecs = mktime("2022 " gensub(/:/," ","g"), 1)
}

NR%2 == 0 {
    dayDeltaSecs += (currSecs - prevSecs)
}

(NR > 1) && (currDate != prevDate) {
    printf "%s: %d seconds\n", prevDate, dayDeltaSecs
    dayDeltaSecs = 0
}

END {
    printf "%s: %d seconds\n", prevDate, dayDeltaSecs
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Jan 1: 20 seconds
Jan 2: 76 seconds
Jan 3: 27 seconds
Jan 4: 6 seconds
```

---

Original answer:

This may be what you're trying to do, using GNU awk for time functions:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    prevEt = epochtime
    $1 = (index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",$1) + 2) / 3
    epochtime = mktime("2022 " gensub(/:/," ","g"), 1)
}
NR%2 == 0 {
    print prevEt, epochtime, epochtime - prevEt
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
1640995796 1640995802 6
1640995845 1640995852 7
```

Comment: Given `mktime` input format I was looking for a concise way to transform a month name prefix to a number when you posted your answer; nice solution ;-)

Comment: I'm not experienced enough to judge what awk is doing here, but I get an error:

`$ awk -f test.awk shortimes`



`awk: test.awk:5:     epochtime = mktime("2022 " gensub(/:/," ","g"), 1)`



`awk: test.awk:5:                                                      ^ 2 is invalid as number of arguments for mktime`

               where the ^2 is pointing to the closing parenthesis of "epochtime" line

Comment: You;re using an old version of gawk that doesn't support a UTC-flag arg for mktime so get a more current gawk version or you'll have to get rid of that `,1` and be sure to set TZ=UTC in your shell before running the awk command.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't update to a newer version of gawk.

Comment: then get rid of the `,1` ...

Comment: Well that is extremely close but the times are incorrect. Exactly how I need it displayed though.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly!